# What is the connection between these two clauses?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the bold-part mean?, in connection to the first part before hyphen?

> Chomsky expresses support for the boycott of products from Israeli settlements in the occupied territories – **a strategy enhanced by an EU policy shift last year that was welcomed by pro-Palestinian activists.**

Answer (score 1):

The word **strategy** refers back to the **boycott of products from Israeli settlements in the occupied territories.**

Answer (score 1):

The connection here just intends to indicate clearly that Chomsky is not the only one having this opinion, but there is an important institution (the EU) which has thought of the same policy before.

In fact, the EU was (is?) thinking of a regulation to force labelling of products made in that Israeli settlements.